# Sql Server can't stop

Tags: sql-server

Today I had a problem with the SQL Server. The SQL Server has crashed and I can't connect to it. When I try to restart the SQL Server it remained in the STOP_Pending state for 30 minutes, then I killed the process.

I have this error message in the error log. I can't find what the error means. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

```
2021-04-12 08:02:07.54 spid755     Unable to create stack dump file due to stack shortage (Location:     scheduler.cpp:2090
Expression:  !pWorker->WorkerQueueElem::IsInList ()
SPID:        755
Process ID:  2336)
2021-04-12 08:02:07.54 spid755     Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000000
2021-04-12 08:02:08.20 spid755     External dump process not executed.

2021-04-12 08:02:08.20 spid755     DoMiniDump () encountered error (0xC00000FD)
2021-04-12 08:02:08.20 spid755     Error: 17066, severity: 16, state: 1.
2021-04-12 08:02:08.20 spid755     SQL Server Assertion: File: <scheduler.cpp>, line=2090 Failed Assertion = '!pWorker->WorkerQueueElem::IsInList ()'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000000000000000
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0009.txt
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      *
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      *   04/12/21 08:02:32 spid 9804
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      *
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * Stalled IOCP Listener
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      *
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-12 08:02:32.01 Server      * Short Stack Dump
```

Comment: *"If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted."* Seems to quite clear on what to do, if I am honest. What part of the error don't you understand here?

Comment: @larnu I just wonder, if OP can't connect as they say, then how are they going to run DBCC on it? Doesn't that require a connection?

Comment: I read it as the the OP said that they couldn't connect to it (for 30 minutes), and killed it, and (I therefore assume) have started the service again. They make no note of what they did *after* they killed it, so I felt it a safe assumption that they then started it again, @PeterB , seeing as that was their goal. If it still wasn't starting, I would also expected them to have told us the start up error they were getting (which they have not).

Comment: Service is running now and i can connet. And i chceked DB via DBCC CHECKDB. But my problem is that I don't know what caused this error

Comment: Crashes are essentially always due to either internal bugs or hardware failures -- even if those were triggered by user action, since SQL Server isn't supposed to crash. Step one would be checking the event logs for things that might indicate hardware failure. If there's no smoking gun there, check if you have the [latest version](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/), and if not update.

Comment: Do a [memory test](http://hs.windows.microsoft.com/hhweb/content/m-en-us/p-6.2/id-4edd5f80-def2-4d32-965c-116d49fb9872/), then `chkdsk`, update to latest drivers, latest Windows patch and latest SQL Server patch in that order.